# Show that $x^4 + 8x - 12$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

> Is there a nice way to show that $x^4 + 8x - 12$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Right now I'm going with the rational root theorem to show there are no linear factors and [this result](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6519/9e8bffa19b89f29ad95379654164ad4e7696.pdf), involving the cubic resolvent, to show there are no irreducible quadratic factors.

Comment: If it is a product of quadratic, it must be $(x^2 +ax +b)(x^2 - ax + c)$ so you have 3 equations in 3 variables

Comment: Which ends up with a cubic, [see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=b*d%3D-12%2C+a*d%2Bb*c%3D8%2C+a*c%2Bb%2Bd%3D0%2C+a%2Bc%3D0) @Exodd And the verification [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=b*d%2B%28a*d%2Bb*c%29*x%2B%28a*c%2Bb%2Bd%29*x%5E2%2B%28a%2Bc%29x%5E3%2Bx%5E4%3D%3D%28x%5E2%2Ba*x%2Bb%29*%28x%5E2%2Bc*x%2Bd%29).

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin those are not the right equations

Comment: $bc=-12$ (with $b, c$ integers) has $12$ possible solutions.  None works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f(x):=x^4+8x-12$.  Then, the polynomial
$$g(x):=f(x+1)=x^4+4x^3+6x^2+12x-3$$
satisfies the hypothesis of the [Extended Eisenstein's Criterion](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) with respect to the prime $3$.  This means $g(x)$ has an irreducible factor of degree at least $3$.  If $f(x)$ is reducible, then $g(x)$ is reducible, so $g(x)$ must have a linear factor.  You now need to show that $g(x)$ has no linear factors, which is not too difficult (i.e., you simply need to check that $g(x)\neq 0$ for $x\in\{\pm 1,\pm3\}$), so the assumption that $f(x)$ is reducible cannot be true.

**Remark.** In general, if you are given a polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and you want to find a prime natural number $p$ such that there exists a "shift" of $f(x)$ to which the Extended Eisenstein's Criterion can be applied, then you look at the discriminant $\Delta(f)$ of $f(x)$.  This prime $p$ should divide $\Delta(f)$.  For $f(x)=x^4+ax+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers, $\Delta(f)=256b^3-27a^4$.
Particularly, when $f(x)=x^4+8x-12$, we get $$\Delta(f)=-552960=-2^{12}\cdot 3^3\cdot 5\,,$$
which mean the choices of possible $p$ are $2$, $3$, and $5$.  Now, $5$ has only exponent $1$ in $\Delta(f)$, which means that no matter how you shift $f$ so that the constant term and the linear term are both $0$ modulo $5$, the quadratic term will not be $0$ modulo $5$.  Therefore, $p=5$ is not a good choice.  The remaining candidates are $p=2$ and $p=3$.  It is clear that $p=2$ will not work well (since $f(x)\equiv x^4\pmod{2}$, so there is not much information to gain).  The best candidate is $p=3$.

Comment: Very nice. I don’t know the extended Eisenstein, but I do see that the only possible factorization is (cubic$\times$linear) by looking at the Newton Polygon in $\Bbb Q_3$. (I suppose that’s what extended Eisenstein does.) The N.P. does tell you that the linear has for its root a $3$-unit, so that means that the only potential roots to check are $\pm1$.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at $f(x-1)=x^4-4x^3+6x^2+4x-19$, you can notice the constant term is a prime. So if there is a factorization, one of the (monic) factors $g(x) \mid f(x-1)$ must have constant term equal $g(0)=\pm 1$. If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_k$ are roots of $g(x)$, i.e. $g(x)=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\dots(x-\alpha_k)$, then $1=|(-1)^k \alpha_1 \alpha_2 \dots \alpha_k|=|\alpha_1| |\alpha_2| \dots |\alpha_k|$. This means at least one of $|\alpha_i| \leq 1$, but since $\alpha_i$ is also root of $f(x-1)$, we have $19=|\alpha_i^4-4\alpha_i^3+6\alpha_i^2+4\alpha_i|$$\leq |\alpha_i|^4+4|\alpha_i|^3+6|\alpha_i|^2+4|\alpha_i|$$\leq 1+4+6+4=15$, impossible.