# Factorization of polynomials into polynomials of smaller degree

Tags: factoring

how 'hard' is the find the factorization of POlynomials ?

i mean for example if we had $ x^4-1 = (x^2-1)(x^2 +1) $

this is easy but if we put the polynomial in general

$$ x^6 -5x^3 +4x^2 -7x^3 =0 $$

then in general how can we 'factorize ' a polynomial into polynomials of lower degree?

Comment: Factoring is very hard.  Even testing for reducibility is hard.

Comment: Your polynomial may have a typo, because $-5x^3-7x^3=-12x^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously we have
$$
x^6 -5x^3 +4x^2 -7x^3 =(x^4 - 12x + 4)x^2,
$$
where the first factor is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.
In general factoring is hard, but there are several algorithms - see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials). For polynomials of lower degree it thus no problem to obtain a factorisation.

To show that a polynomial like $x^4-12x+4$ is irreducible, one often can use the [extended Eisenstein criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748727/show-that-x4-8x-12-is-irreducible-in-mathbbqx). Also, a [direct computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579410/prove-x6-6x412x2-11-is-irreducible-over-mathbbq) is possible for low degree, and several other criteria.